# ArgumentError (string contains null byte) when uploading file in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, roo-gem

I am trying to use the roo gem to run some operations on an excel File.  This works perfectly when I do it manually:

```
file = File.join(Rails.root, 'october_data.xlsx')
spreadsheet = Roo::Excelx.new(file)
```

However, this does not work when I upload the file via a form:

```
file = File.read params["Team Changes"]["document"].path
spreadsheet = Roo::Excelx.new(file)
```

I get the following error:

```
 ArgumentError (string contains null byte)
```

There seems to be a lot written about `string contains null byte` but nothing I've seen seems relevant to what I'm working on.  How do I fix this?

Comment: How does the params look? can you post them?

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me. Apparently it is an encoding issue.
Try specifying encoding to 'ASCII-8BIT' when you read the file.

```
file = File.read(params["Team Changes"]["document"].path, encoding: 'ASCII-8BIT')
spreadsheet = Roo::Excelx.new(file)
```